# jQuery gallery not triggering after Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I am using a jQuery pop-up script [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html). It works well in a WooCommerce store but when I filter products using an Ajax Filter Plugin ([YITH](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/)) it stops triggering. I understand this is because Ajax has changed the page and so the event is no longer bound to the link class in the page but not sure how to solve it.

From what I have read I can use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) but I am unsure how this applies to the way I am triggering the Magnific Popup script which is below.

```
jQuery('.product').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    midClick: true,
    gallery:{
        enabled:false
    },
    delegate: 'a.wpb_wl_preview',
    removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
    callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {
           this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
        }
    },
    closeOnContentClick: false,
});
```

Comment: I do not know Magnific, but try to just change the element on which you apply it, put it above in the DOM tree... Add it to an element which won't change on ajax call. Or you can simply rerun this code on every ajax call end.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It is a list of products which changes with filters, so most of the page changes. The trigger for the pop-up is on every product in the list. I'll see if there is a way to rerun the code.

Comment: what you can try is to attach the event to the parent dom $('parent').on('click', 'dynamic elementclass', fn);

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I have found there is a jQuery function to detect when Ajax has been executed which is below. Not sure if this is the best method, so interested to see other answers but this works.

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {

 //code to trigger here

});
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was suggesting, but you could also use the ajax call's success callback so your code doesn't run every ajax call, but just on the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about that? Presumably I'd need to dig in to the Wordpress plugin making the Ajax calls and add a snippet in there.

Comment: Yes, if you do not own the code it's gonna be a bit harder... I suggest you read the doc about the parameter functions so you can test on the request to make sure you run your code only when it needs to. Also, note that the doc do not say which handler will run first (your plugin's or this one) this might become problematic